# How do I give animation in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to create an application where I want to give Angular animation to a `span`.
I took reference from this example [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-collapsible-block?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I tried to create my own `span` after that. I have created a [MyStackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-obcl1t?file=src/app/app.component.html) here to provide an example what I am doing.

As shown in example, I want to add **collapse animation** to that `span`.

I have tried doing that from the reference example I have provided, but I am stuck at a point where I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it closer to the example you are trying to copy you would need to do the following.

First you would need to import [BrowserAnimationsModule](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/BrowserAnimationsModule) to your module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Next you would need to move your `[@collapse]="collapsed"` to the `div#detailsid` as you are trying to animate that element, not `span#user` trigger/icon/button. Also remove `[hidden]="isShow"` as the visibility/height is handled by the animations applying `height` and `visibility`:

```
<div id="detailsid" [@collapse]="collapsed">
  <!-- your stuff -->
</div>
```

Finally you will need to update your CSS to have `div#detailsid` to have `overflow: hidden;`

```
#detailsid {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m1nvfw?file=src/app/app.component.html) mostly working.